# How to find the index of the second, non-sequential occurrence of a value in a vector using R?

Tags: r

I need to find the index of the second, non-sequential, occurrence of a value in a vector.

Some example vectors:

Example a) 1 1 1 2 3 4 1 1 1 2 3 4

Example b) 1 2 3 1 1 1 3 5

Note that vectors can have different number of occurrences of each value and are very large (more than 100000 entries)

So, if the value in question is 1, in example a) the result should return the 7th position, and b) should return the 4th.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice you can provide.

Examples Code:

```
exampleA<-c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
exampleB<-c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks all for your rapid and thorough assistance. I ultimately chose the answer by @josliber because I was able to follow the logic most easily (the others all contributed something valuable but a couple were beyond my skills), and it introduced me to the rle function, which I was unfamiliar with and looks very useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The run-length encoding of a vector can be helpful in these sorts of computations:

```
find.index <- function(x, value) {
  r <- rle(x)
  match.pos <- which(r$value == value)
  if (length(match.pos) < 2) {
    return(NA)  # There weren't two sequential sets of observations
  }
  return(sum(r$length[1:(match.pos[2]-1)])+1)
}

# Test it out
a <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
b <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5)
find.index(a, 1)
# [1] 7
find.index(b, 1)
# [1] 4
find.index(b, 5)
# [1] NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a combination of `which` and `diff` could be of use:

```
x <- which(a == 1)
x[which(diff(x) != 1)[1] + 1]
# [1] 7
y <- which(b == 1)
y[which(diff(y) != 1)[1] + 1]
# [1] 4
```

---

Here it is as a function:

```
findFirst <- function(invec, value, event) {
  x <- which(invec == value)
  if (event == 1) out <- x[1]
  else out <- x[which(diff(x) != 1)[event-1] + 1]
  out
}
```

- `invec` is the input vector.
- `value` is the value you're looking for.
- `event` is the position (for example, first, second, third sequence).

Usage would be:

```
findFirst(a, 1, 2)   ## event is the occurrence you want to get
```

---

Benchmarking the functions available so far:

```
set.seed(1)
a <- sample(25, 1e7, replace = TRUE)
findFirst(a, 10, 2)
# [1] 14
find.index(a, 10)
# [1] 14
op(a, 10)
# [1] 14

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(findFirst(a, 10, 2), find.index(a, 10), op(a, 10), times = 5)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                 expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#  findFirst(a, 10, 2)  281.6979  284.3281  301.6595  380.9089  414.9640     5
#    find.index(a, 10) 3268.0227 3312.0002 3372.3713 3444.7334 3769.0176     5
#            op(a, 10)  272.7325  278.3369  280.3172  286.0758  293.6699     5
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an R only implementation that is surprisingly faster than Rcpp, though we're not going very deep in the vector so I don't know if that's meaningful.

```
find.index.3 <- function(vec, val) {
  seq_val <- 0
  last_val <- NA
  for(i in seq_along(vec)) {
    if(identical(vec[[i]], val) & !identical(last_val, val_to_match))
      if(identical(seq_val <- seq_val + 1, 2)) break
    last_val <- vec[[i]]
  }
  i
}
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(find.index.3(a, 10L), find.second(a, 10))
# Unit: milliseconds
#                  expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
#  find.index.3(a, 10L)  5.650716  5.877447  6.095766  8.003047 106.4033   100
#    find.second(a, 10) 15.758154 18.143398 18.934030 20.247239 118.1735   100
```

The key is to avoid using vectorized functions that look over the entire vector.  This could well be slower if the repeating instance is deep in the vector.  Note that `identical()` is supposedly pretty fast (EDIT: actually, using `==` seems to be faster), but it means you have to pass your value as an integer.

EDIT:

Rcpp does get faster if you go deep enough.  Changing `a` so it samples from 10,000 values instead of 25 you get:

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#                  expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  find.index.3(a, 10L) 80.50039 83.23213 84.27801 85.43654 186.4049   100
#    find.second(a, 10) 17.06515 19.38969 20.52041 23.52533 125.8619   100
```

Comment: Cool analysis with deep vs. not deep here

Comment: @josilber, thanks though it's funny that after all that trouble in your second answer and here the OP goes with your original slow answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
op <- function(v, x){ # v=vector, x=value
    w <- which(v==x) # 1)
    s <- seq(w[1],length.out=length(w)) # 2)
    return(w[which(w!=s)[1]]) # 3)
}

> exampleA <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
> exampleB <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5)
> op(exampleA, 1)
[1] 7
> op(exampleB, 1)
[1] 4
```

1. Check what elements in the vector are equal to `x`.
2. Build a sequence `s` from the position of the first element equal to `x`.
3. `w==s=TRUE` are those occurrences that are consecutive from the first occurrence, so you want to return the first position where `w!=s`, that is, that is not consecutive from the first one.

Comment: +1. Seems pretty efficient (by the benchmark in my answer). It would be nice to generalize the function a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

If speed is a big factor here (and, reading the original post, it seems like it may be), then a custom solution using Rcpp is likely to be faster than any of the pure-R approaches posted so far:

```
library(Rcpp)
find.second = cppFunction(
"int findSecond(NumericVector x, const int value) {
    bool startFirst = false;
    bool inFirst = false;
    for (int i=0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
        if (x[i] == value) {
            if (!startFirst) {
                startFirst = true;
                inFirst = true;
            } else if (!inFirst) {
                return i+1;
            }
        } else {
            inFirst = false;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}")
```

Here are @AnandMahto's benchmarks, expanded to include `find.second`:

```
set.seed(1)
a <- sample(25, 1e7, replace = TRUE)
findFirst(a, 10, 2)
# [1] 14
find.index(a, 10)
# [1] 14
op(a, 10)
# [1] 14
find.second(a, 10)
# [1] 14

microbenchmark(findFirst(a, 10, 2), find.index(a, 10), op(a, 10), find.second(a, 10), times = 5)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                 expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
#  findFirst(a, 10, 2)   79.00000   93.85400   96.80120  118.32011  121.56636     5
#    find.index(a, 10) 1620.83892 1673.72124 1689.06826 1747.42781 2145.90346     5
#            op(a, 10)   78.54637   83.71081   94.20531   97.30813  195.78469     5
#   find.second(a, 10)   14.57835   24.36220   25.24104   36.57584   47.45959     5
```